# Is missing delete undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-lawyer

When I allocate memory and do not call `delete`, is this undefined behaviour?

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int* a = new int[1];
    // next code only to prevent optimization (hopefully)
    *a = argc; std::cout << *a << std::endl;
    // no delete
    return 0;
}
```

(Let us assume the `new` is not optimized out).

Comment: No, this is defined behavior: a memory leak. Since your program exits right afterwards, the OS will still reclaim all its memory, though.

Comment: What do you mean by optimized out?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks for the link, did not found it be search...

Answer (score 0):

It's not undefined behaviour; it's a memory leak.

Of course leaks "exist" only as long as the process is still running; in this case the process exits (and the concept of leak becomes moot) immediately afterwards.

Comment: I would say it is undefined behaviour, since the program relies on side-effects of the call to the destructor (i.e. the program could run out of memory if it isn't called.) But it isn't crystal clear.

Comment: Who downvoted this and why? I would like to understand if a statement is wrong or something? (upvoted)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Sorry, what? The program clearly does not rely on any side effects, there is no destructor to begin with because `int[]` is not a class type, and running out of memory is not undefined behavior anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I still had [a similar, recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136120/what-is-wrong-with-using-arrays-dynamically-allocated-in-c) in my head, where the array was one of `std::string`.